# Open folder as project in PhpStorm

Tags: windows, phpstorm, jetbrains-toolbox

When I install PhpStorm from JetBrains Toolbox app I do not have an option to open folders as project when right clicking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly JetBrains Toolbox App does not provide such functionality. Only standalone installer has an option to make them right now. You will have to either use that... or create such entries manually.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-2478 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.

---

To add an entry to the Windows Explorer's right-click menu:

- you can use [FileTypesMan by NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) or a similar tool.
- or create such entry manually, e.g. see this comment for a basic `.bat` file: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114307#comment=27-2125363 (at very least it lists Registry keys where to create such an entry).

Answer (score -1):

I found this from Jet Brains :

Click Open on the Welcome screen or select File | Open from the main menu.

In the Select Path dialog, select the directory that contains the project to open.

Drag the desired project from your file chooser right to the Open Project dialog without locating it there. The respective file in the dialog will be found automatically.

Specify whether you want to open the project in a new window, close the current project and reuse the existing window, or open the new project in the same window with the current one. Refer to the Opening multiple projects section for details.

and for the command line you could use this :
`<PhpStorm> <path_to_the_project folder>`
See Open files from the command line for more information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).